# Can someone identify this plant please

Tags: identification

I need help to identify a plant which is almost growing wild in my garden. It's a large cactus type plant with long sword-like leaves and a central stem with lots of white bell shaped flowers. I suppose a lily type leaf but these are solid.

Answer (score 4):

Even without a picture I can tell it is a [yucca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yucca), most likely Yucca filamentosa.
This genus is native to Central and North America.  Members grow in Mexico and Yucca glauca as far north as USDA zone 4.

They are adaptable but certainly look better in sunny well drained sites.  On moist soils or heavy clay I have seen the leaves get some dark spots indicative of a virus or fungus.

Comment: My least favorite plant.  Ugh.  Getting rid of it is a task as well.